# Using moment.utc() incorrectly converting the date into utc format of "days" format-Moment Javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using moment library to convert date into a utc format. here is my date string:

`var dateString = "2019-01-31T11:33:16.952+0000";`

`new Date("2019-01-31T11:33:16.952+0000") // o/p: Thu Jan 31 2019 03:33:16 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)`
since this date is less than a week from today's date, I'm trying to display a text saying "n days ago" instead of actual date. But for some reason I'm getting a future date displayed as "6 days ago" when I do this:

```
moment.utc("2019-01-31T11:33:16.952+0000").local().fromNow() // shouldnt this display "5 days ago"??
```

Not sure why moment is not converting the date correctly, any ideas what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess(Considering use of local() converts to your local timezone so time is deducted because you might be in -ve TimeZone) [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18753773/6517383) is a solution you're expecting:

> Ideally, you would want to pass a UTC timestamp from your server to
>   the client. That doesn't mean you have to switch your whole server
>   over to UTC, it just means that you would convert from the time in
>   your database to UTC on the server before sending it over the web.
>   Sure, it would be even better if you actually stored times in UTC, but
>   you said you aren't in a position to make that sort of change right
>   now. But let's just work off the assumption that you can't change
>   anything at all on the server.
>
> We'll also assume that your server is fixed to the UTC-07:00 offset.
>   In real life, this would only be true for places like Arizona that
>   don't follow daylight saving time. So if you are in Los Angeles and
>   are in Pacific Time, then some of your data is based on UTC-07:00, but
>   some of it is based on UTC-08:00. That requires a lot more work if you
>   want to do it in JavaScript.
>
> Let's also assume that the input is already a string in ISO8601
>   format. (If it's not, then let me know and I will adjust this code.)
>
> var s = "2013-09-11 18:00:00";  // from action.timeStamp
>
> var actionTime = moment(s + "-07:00", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZ");
>
> var timeAgo = actionTime.fromNow(); The reason your other code didn't
>   work is because in the first line, you are affected by the time zone
>   of the browser. The zone setter in the second line just changes the
>   zone for formatting, not changing the actual moment in time.
>
> Also, when you dump a moment to the console for debugging, make sure
>   you format it for output. Otherwise you are just looking at its
>   internal property values, which may or may not make sense directly.