# moment.fromNow() timezone issue

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am getting post of news from server with date that doesnt includes timezone, i know that posts is from EST time zone, example : March 30, 2020 at 10:53 AM (-5 GMT); When post was just updated like few seconds ago moment.fromNow() showing me it was posted like 8 hours ago becasue i am living in +3 GMT. What should i do so that moment.fromNow() showing right time posts was updated without taking difference in time zones. Sorry for my english. 
My code:

```js
...
const dateMoment = moment(date, 'MMMM DD, YYYY h:mm A');
news.date = dateMoment.toDate();
...

//in component

<Text style={styles.cardDate}> {moment(news.date).fromNow()} </Text> //getting text '8 hours ago' even if it was posted right now 
...

 {moment(news.date).tz('America/New_York').fromNow()} // didn't work too, still 8 hours difference
```

Comment: You probably want [`from`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/from/), and that value of now in EST.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was my mistake. I parsed date wrong. The right way was :

```js
const dateMoment = moment(date, 'MMMM DD, YYYY h:mm A').tz('America/New_York', true);
news.date = dateMoment.toDate();
```

I should have set `keepLocalTime` to `true` in `tz(timezone: string, keepLocalTime?: boolean): moment.Moment`.

Now i just use in component:

```js
<Text style={styles.cardDate}> {moment(news.date).fromNow()} </Text>
```

And actualy timezone was wrong too, it's not New York it's LA...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the time to a specific timezone, you can try giving it a [`utcOffset`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/), like -

```
{ moment(news.date).utcOffset('-05:00').fromNow() }
```

Comment: did not work, sadly, i  tryed variants from here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752366/using-timezones-with-moment-js-fromnow-or-from , nothing working for me